# By accident I removed Desktop folder in Gnome desktop. Now I see all folders and files from ~/home on my desktop screen

Tags: gnome, display, screen, home-directory

I was doing some "house kipping" aka deleting some ancient files and folders to free the space on my disk. I worked in Doublecmd and somehow marked the Desktop folder. After deleting finished my desktop was cluttered with all folders and files in my home folder. I restored the Desktop from the trash but the process broke. After reboot, there is a plethora of objects on my screen I don't want to see them there.
How do I set up Gnome-desktop to read the Desktop folder in my ~/home instead of my basic home folder?
Thanks to anyone who would find the time to answer.

Comment: A good place to start if what version of Ubuntu are yous using?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the directory "Desktop" is back in its proper place, i.e. in your home directory. Then open the configuration file `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs` with a text editor and make sure the line for `XDG_DESKTOP` reads like `XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/Desktop"`. Log out then back in.